# What does TPMc stand for?

Tags: performance, cpu, acronym

I need to provide some performance values for a server specification and I've been asked to provide TPMc values. What does it stand for and where can I find this value for specific processors? (If it is even related to a processor performance measurement...)

I've checked several manufacturer's web pages and couldn't find this value anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The performance metric reported by [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/detail.asp) measures the number of orders that can be fully processed per minute and is expressed in **tpm-C**.

…

> As an OLTP system benchmark, TPC-C simulates a complete environment where a population of terminal operators executes transactions against a database. The benchmark is centered around the principal activities (transactions) of an order-entry environment. These transactions include entering and delivering orders, recording payments, checking the status of orders, and monitoring the level of stock at the warehouses. However, it should be stressed that it is not the intent of TPC-C to specify how to best implement an Order-Entry system. While the benchmark portrays the activity of a wholesale supplier, TPC-C is not limited to the activity of any particular business segment, but, rather, represents any industry that must manage, sell, or distribute a product or service.

With this sort of benchmark, it is not just the CPU that is being measured. I believe that manufacturers usually pay for TPC benchmarking of a specific system configuration.

The TPC publish the [results](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_results.asp?orderby=hardware)

Comment: hmm I believe is TPMc, as the server has nothing to do with a database... also this data is required right next to the # of cores for the processor...

Comment: @FelipeSabino: "The performance metric reported by TPC-C measures the number of orders that can be fully processed per minute and is expressed in **tpm-C**." From [TPC overview](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/detail.asp) - I'll update my answer to state this.

Answer (score 0):

TpmC is a benchmark rating from [TPC](http://www.tpc.org/default.asp) (Transaction Processing Performance Council) that measures the overall transaction processing performance of a system. It is my understanding that this metric is based on the overall system performance, thus tpmC would not be published for processors on their own.